# Extract personal website details from Text file

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to extract the personal website details from a text file. Let’s consider we have below links in text file. How can I extract only github, stackoverflow and wordpress url from this?

```
https://github.com/XYZ

github.com/abcd

linkedin.com/in/ahgf

abcd.wordpress.com/

www.google.com

https://play.google.com/store/search?

https://stackoverflow/sampath

stackoverflow.com/abcdv
```

I used below regex to extract:

```
urls = re.findall('(?:(?:(?:ftp|http)[s]*:\/\/|www\.)[^\.]+\.[^ \n]+)', text)

return urls
```

But the output was:

```
https://github.com/XYZ

https://play.google.com/store/search?

https://stackoverflow/sampath
```

Required output:

```
https://github.com/XYZ

github.com/abcd

linkedin.com/in/ahgf

abcd.wordpress.com/

https://stackoverflow/sampath

stackoverflow.com/abcdv
```

I achieved this for pdf file using below code:

```
import pdfx

pdf = pdfx.PDFx('E:/cvparser/backupresumes/xyz.pdf')

metadata = pdf.get_metadata()

reference_list = pdf.get_references()

reference_dict = pdf.get_references_as_dict()

r = [x for x in reference_dict['url'] if 'stackoverflow' in x or 'linkedin' in x or 'github' in x or 'wordpress' in x]

print (r)
```

Can someone tell me how can I achieve this for text files? Either by using regex patterns or by any python modules?

Comment: you talk about text files without defined formatting like html for example? If so - in principle, simple string matching (like in your pdf file example) is faster and easier, but `regex` is much more powerful. But also more complicated of course. Maybe this can help you get the patterns right: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most efficient way, but if you need it for something simple, the code below should do it.

```
output = []
links = ['github', 'stackoverflow', 'wordpress']
with open('/path/to/input_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        for link in links:
            if link in line:
                output.append(line)

print(output)
```

The idea is to iterate over the lines of the file and then check to see if any of the urls you desire are present in that line by iterating over a list of urls and checking each of them against the content of the line.